# error in send email using Mandrill (php)

Tags: php, email, mandrill

I am using mandrill api for the first time. I am using following code.
I have Mandrill API Key with me.

```
 <?php
    try {
        $mandrill = new Mandrill('YOUR_API_KEY');
        $message = array(
            'html' => '<p>Example HTML content</p>',
            'text' => 'Example text content',
            'subject' => 'example subject',
            'from_email' => 'message.from_email@example.com',
            'from_name' => 'Example Name',
            'to' => array(
                array(
                    'email' => 'recipient.email@example.com',
                    'name' => 'Recipient Name'
                )
            ),
            'headers' => array('Reply-To' => 'message.reply@example.com'),
            'important' => false,
            'track_opens' => null,
            'track_clicks' => null,
            'auto_text' => null,
            'auto_html' => null,
            'inline_css' => null,
            'url_strip_qs' => null,
            'preserve_recipients' => null,
            'view_content_link' => null,
            'bcc_address' => 'message.bcc_address@example.com',
            'tracking_domain' => null,
            'signing_domain' => null,
            'return_path_domain' => null,
            'merge' => true,
            'global_merge_vars' => array(
                array(
                    'name' => 'merge1',
                    'content' => 'merge1 content'
                )
            ),
            'merge_vars' => array(
                array(
                    'rcpt' => 'recipient.email@example.com',
                    'vars' => array(
                        array(
                            'name' => 'merge2',
                            'content' => 'merge2 content'
                        )
                    )
                )
            ),
            'tags' => array('password-resets'),
            'subaccount' => 'customer-123',
            'google_analytics_domains' => array('example.com'),
            'google_analytics_campaign' => 'message.from_email@example.com',
            'metadata' => array('website' => 'www.example.com'),
            'recipient_metadata' => array(
                array(
                    'rcpt' => 'recipient.email@example.com',
                    'values' => array('user_id' => 123456)
                )
            ),
            'attachments' => array(
                array(
                    'type' => 'text/plain',
                    'name' => 'myfile.txt',
                    'content' => 'ZXhhbXBsZSBmaWxl'
                )
            ),
            'images' => array(
                array(
                    'type' => 'image/png',
                    'name' => 'IMAGECID',
                    'content' => 'ZXhhbXBsZSBmaWxl'
                )
            )
        );
        $async = false;
        $ip_pool = 'Main Pool';
        $send_at = 'example send_at';
        $result = $mandrill->messages->send($message, $async, $ip_pool, $send_at);
        print_r($result);

    } catch(Mandrill_Error $e) {
        echo 'A mandrill error occurred: ' . get_class($e) . ' - ' . $e->getMessage();

        throw $e;
    }
    ?>
```

By using this code I am getting error as:

A mandrill error occurred: Mandrill_HttpError - API call to messages/send failed: error setting certificate verify locations: CAfile: /usr/local/share/certs/ca-root-nss.crt CApath: none

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple php function to send an email with Mandrill](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14473592/simple-php-function-to-send-an-email-with-mandrill)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the error is indicating you don't have the required SSL cert installed locally to verify the SSL connection with Mandrill's API.  You can get a bundle of certs through a package manager for your operating system, or you can download the bundle that's distributed with Mozilla: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html and then store them locally.

Comment: after download the cert, add to PHP.ini:
curl.cainfo = "PATH_TO/cacert.pem"

Comment: I'm still getting the same error after downloading the pem file and adding curl.cainfo = c:\wamp\cacert.pem to php.ini

Comment: somehow i am also not able to get it solved even after downloading certification and configuring in correct php.ini file! but many suggests only this is right solution

Answer (score 27):

At this file:
 mandrill-api-php\src\Mandrill.php

At line 58 where initialize curl:

```
$this->ch = curl_init();
```

You need to add this two options to solve the problem:

```
curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
```

Or you have this option to:
[HTTPS and SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed, CA is OK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6400300/php-curl-https-causing-exception-ssl-certificate-problem-verify-that-the-ca-cer/16495053#16495053)

Comment: this didn't help... .

Comment: If you set those two options to 0, you're effectively turning off SSL verification, which opens you up to potential security vulnerabilities, and is definitely not recommended.

Comment: I use this only in localhost, because I couldn't make it work with cert on Windows. For production this is commented

Answer (score 5):

After downloading cacert.pem from http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html and putting it on my server, I was able to fix this problem (while keeping everything secure) with the following:

```
$mandrill = new Mandrill(MANDRILL_API_KEY);

// Fix CA issue
curl_setopt($mandrill->ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, true);
curl_setopt($mandrill->ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($mandrill->ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, 'PATH_TO/cacert.pem');
```

The curl property in the Mandrill class is public, so there is no need to add hacks to the library itself.

Comment: This worked for me but, JFYI, `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` should be set to `2` not `true`, true was deprecated.