# Sending email with Mandrill using PHP

Tags: php, mandrill

I'm trying to send email using Mandrill and PHP and I can't get it to send.

I've downloaded the PHP API wrapper from here:https://packagist.org/packages/mandrill/mandrill

Mandrill.php is in my root and the Mandrill folder is in the same directory.

Here's my code:

```
<?php
require_once 'Mandrill.php';

$mandrill = new Mandrill('MY API KEY IS USUALLY HERE');
$message = array(
    'subject' => 'Test message',
    'from_email' => 'jwjody@yahoo.com',
    'from_name' => 'Sender person',
    'html' => '<p>this is a test message with Mandrill\'s PHP wrapper!.</p>',
    'to' => array(array('email' => 'jwjody@yahoo.com', 'name' => 'Recipient 1')),
    'merge_vars' => array(array(
        'rcpt' => 'recipient1@domain.com',
        'vars' =>
        array(
            array(
                'name' => 'FIRSTNAME',
                'content' => 'Recipient 1 first name'),
            array(
                'name' => 'LASTNAME',
                'content' => 'Last name')
    ))));

//print_r($mandrill->messages->sendTemplate($template_name, $template_content, $message));
echo ("hello");

?>
```

But it won't send. I'm not sure where the failure is. Is it something obvious I'm missing?

I see the issue now.

I see what's going on now!

I changed

```
$mandrill->messages->sendTemplate($template_name, $template_content, $message));
```

to

```
$mandrill->messages->send($message, $async=false, $ip_pool=null, $send_at=null);
```

And it works!

Comment: What is the result you get after uncommenting the print_r?

Comment: Have you tried to debug at all?  Have your checked you error logs?  Have you checked your queue for sendmail (or whatever mechanism you server uses)?

Comment: @Morgan I took the code on how to send using PHP from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14473592/simple-php-function-to-send-an-email-with-mandrill/14486237#14486237

But I'm not using a template. So the print statement is commented out for now.

Comment: @MikeBrant I'm not quite sure what kind of debugging to do. I put the echo in at the end to make sure something was happening.

Comment: Now that you've figured out what you did, you should write what you did as an answer to your question and accept it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of calling the sendTemplate() function I should have used

```
$mandrill->messages->send($message, $async=false, $ip_pool=null, $send_at=null);
```

Once I changed the function call the mail was sent.

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed all of your code with the answer. Because you commented out print_r, I cannot tell why this is the fix as it would be commented out in your original code.